Localized interference between 2 distant points
Lets say an emitter sends a directional carrier wave of 60 Hz that can travel up to 100 km.
Then, at 50 km from source, another weaker wave of 60 Hz is emitted.
This weaker wave is off phase compared to the carrier. (We don't know by how much), and it can only reach about 5 km. It’s not directional, and it’s very close to the line of sight of the first, stronger wave.
Finally, at the other end of the 100 km, in the line of sight of the first emitter, is the receiver.
It's my understanding that receiver would not observe a clean carrier wave, but rather a noisy one due to the weaker signal interference, even though the weaker signal cannot reach it.
Am I wrong on this?

What is the mechanism that you think would cause this to happen? Waves bumping into each other or something?

Yes , more specifically, constructive / destructive interference

where are you getting these range-imited signals from?

If waves bumped into each other like you suggest, radio communication would be impossible. They don't.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні in this hypothetical scenario, the emitter is producing the signal. The type of emitter is not specified.

@Finbarr could you point me as to why interference do not apply in this scenario?

Waves do not interfere with each other. Try pointing two torch beams across each other and see if anything changes.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_interference
Mmm cant seem to figure out what am i getting wrong after reading this ?

The interference only takes place at the point where you observe it, i.e. the receiver. If one wave never reaches it there will be no interference.

A small clarification, the emitter does not have a finite range (5 or 100 km). The wave will propagate indefinitely, albeit weaker with distance. The Voyager spacecraft only transmit approximately 20W of RF power, yet the signal are received here on earth. The real life range limitations arise as the signal will get too weak to detect as the receiver is subject other sources of noise and any processing electronics will contribute noise even inside the receiver. So for the Voyager craft, the complexity required to receive the signals would be immense - massive high gain antenna, ultra low noise cryogenically cooled amplifiers and a host of advanced signal processing.
It not clear in the question, but I'll assume in the vicinity of emitter 2, the field strength due to emitter 2 is higher than emitter 1. This is not unreasonable in real life, due to the field strength falling with the square of distance. the field strength due to my mobile phone (next to me) is probably higher than that due to the TV transmitter (20km away), despite it transmitting 100,000 times more power.
I'll present two scenarios:
1. Noise free, no thermal noise and no external interference.
Given the question stated both were 60Hz (and I'll presume high purity sine sources) received signal would be vector sum of the signal due to each.
A receiver placed near the 0km or 100km point, then the received signal would be dominated by the emitter 1. As you approach the 50km point the total received signal would be dominated by emitter 2.
There would possibly be two points where destructive interference occurs. For this to happen the wave received by both source need to have the same amplitude but opposite phase. This would need to be a bit below and above 50 km. This arise as the received power falling with the square of distance to the emitter. So going from 50 to 51 km results in the signal from emitter 1 only reducing a little but for emitter 2 the change is 0 to 1km, a huge relative change.
But at no point would the received signal be noisy even though "interference" is occurring.
2. With realistic noise.
The signal to noise ratio at 100km is only determined by the effective noise at the receiver and the strength of the emitter 1. The question stated emitter 2 only had a short range, I'll interpret this to mean after 5km the signal level is below the receiver noise floor. This means turning emitter 2 on and off has no discernible effect on the received signal at 100km. If emitter 2 was stronger, then it would contribute a small phase shift to the received signal at 100km.
Technically in this scenario, the vector addition is always occurring, just like in 1. It's just the small changes in phase and amplitude due the vector sum may be masked by random noise.
But the noise is never a function of emitter 2.

In the hypothetical world where waves are range limited the 5km waves cannot be seen by the receiver at 100km (50km distant from the 5km source)
In the theoretical world where waves weaken on a perfect inverse square law it can be calculated that the 5km wave as seen by the receiver seen at 50km will be 25 times weaker (power level) than the 100km seen at 100km.
In the real world there are too many sources of 60Hz waves to perform this experiment.

Interesting. So if i understand correctly, in this theorical world, the receiver would see a signal with small (25x weaker) deformations on its amplitude readings ?

phase shift and/or amplitude change depending ow how the two signals line up phase-wise.

But if you can measure this it means the signal was probably strong enough to be measurable at 50km distance given the right receiver.
